# Gimp paintbrush blendmodes usage

Tags: gimp, blending, painting

While I can understand singularly every blend mode of the paintbrush from the math point of view, I cannot find a use for most of them (the only ones I used are for drawing a castle and these were "Color,Value,Saturation").

So I'd like to know how do you use/used blend modes (of the paintbrush! I'm NOT interested in blending layers) to paint your pictures in GIMP.

Please avoid "this take 50% of the color from channel blah" answers (I understand the math).

I'd like answers that are (possibily short) sentences that explain the goal and why that blend mode was right for that task. If it is also possible showing a small piece of image before and after application of the paintbrush and the shape of the paintbrush that would be an additional point!

(Photoshop answers counts as long as the same blending mode exist in GIMP, I'll check everything and if works the same.).

I start:

**Saturation:** I wanted to grey-en certain parts of the image, the saturation mode allowed to do that. This is cool if you exagerate with color, or if you want to make more vivid certain part of the images by increasing the saturation.

**Value:**  I wanted to brighten-darken certain parts of the image to adjust highlights or shadows.

Thanks.

EDIT:
To be more precise, I don't want answers like "Pencil is used to change color of pixels along a path to foreground color in selected layer". If the answer end up in saying "this math operation is applied to pixels" than it is usefull to noone and anyway would just be a copy of what GIMP documentation already says.

A more usefull answer is "Pencil is used to draw lines".

Comment: If you know what the layer modes do, then I do not understand why the paint modes - at least those that are also there for layers - would be such a mystery to you.

Comment: Knowing a tool and using it are 2 TOTAL DIFFERENT THINGS. Have you ever tried painting from scratch with the paintbrush using some blendmode different from "Normal"?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there's an on-topic and valid question here or not. I mean I think the topic is fascinating but the GDSE is primarily focused on factually answering specific questions and this seems more like an exploration tools and how others use them...

Comment: in that case should I move the question on another exchange site?

Comment: well, if that is usefull to you, I requested usage examples because I feared people just browsed GIMP documentation and posted the math formula of how it works (so I wanted answers like: "Pencil is used to draw lines" . 
I wanted to avoid an answer like: "Pencil convert pixel colors along its path to foreground color" wich is useless and usefull for noone since that would be a copy of GIMP documentation)

Comment: Ah, your question made me think that you know how to use layer blend modes and what they will do to the image and when to use them, but were actually wondering why one would want them for a paint tool. But I guess that you'd ask the same for layer blend modes, except that you aren't right now, right?

Comment: Since the Adobe documentation team has already done this in their Photoshop Help documents, I'll just [point to their work](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blending-modes.html). When to use each blending mode is really up to each artist or designer and the particular effect they need to achieve. But the Adobe documentation does note some use cases where a particular blending mode tends to be used.

Comment: it is not the same @Micheal. You are assuming that I can paint a black and white image so that blended on top of my image with correct filter gives the wanted result. But AFAIK human beings(unless someone is really a very talented artist) are not able to do that. First images are colored while a paintbrush usually is "black/white". Second if you see changes while you paint you can make incremental adjustments wich is impossible by designing a image up-front. I assume then you never painted from scratch. The algorithm behind may be the same, but the result is really different

Comment: Also keep in mind that multiple strokes are applied to an already modified version of the image while blending layers is done with 2 "untouched" images, another reason that yields a different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I use Krita on my works, but blend modes are essentialy the same thing, math operations, maybe somes I will talk here exist only in Krita, but as there is no answer, here it goes:

**Addition**
I use it to create intense specular light effects and glowing areas.

**Color dodge**
it did not "flare" as addition but in contrast it produce much more saturated light, it is good for "neon" light effects. **Color dodge** may be better than **linear dodge**, as linear dodge damage a lot dark areas and we are very sensitive to small variations in darker tones.

**Overlay**
I use it to boost contrast and make colors more vivid, it can ruin the image so I'm careful with it because it can ruin the work oversaturating it, it can be used to add patterns too, making the pattern layer work in overlay mode.

**Lighten**
I use it to build fog levels based on darker distant areas as it lighten only areas that are darker than the brush color

**greater**
I use it in help to paint transparent glasses,dresses,etc. It is helpful to paint transparently uniform area because it did not allow the layer to surpass brush transparency, so multiple strokes don't overlay.

**multiply**
simplified shadows, dark patterns. I recommend not abusing it, "shadows have their own color, are not only light based"

**soft light**
soft sun light casting from windows, soft light casts...

> I would like to add that programs like Krita have a ridiculous
>   huge list of blend modes, but a small number are really useful.
>   Keeping it simple, in my view, is the best approach in digital
>   painting, it is as simple as traditional, you don't need dozens of
>   brushes and blending modes, the majority have a reduced use and abusing
>   this can result in weird results, so my advise is, paint as a 
>   traditional artist (mix colors with brushes) and minimally complement
>   with special brushes and blend modes to avoid weird results and 
>   mechanical/stamp strokes. 
>   I point it because many people may read it, and generally come to digital expecting the computer to "compose" their work for them. Not to point digital painting has it's own problems.

**screen, addition, linear dodge, divide, color dodge** are not "light brushes" it will look weird if used everywhere.

**burn, darker, subtract multiply** are not "shadow brushes", it will look weird if used everywhere.

**color** + black and white (value) painting is not the same as painting yourself with colors, it will look "grayish" and in lack of contrast, you can mitigate it using **overlay** and **color dodge** but using brush with normal colors will produce different results.

Comment: Even if Krita naming is not the same exact of GIMP, I think I found most corrispondencies, I tried every single blend mode like you showed and it was really great. Thanks for sharing your experience.